# После установки пакетов не запускается telegram в Debian

Tags: debian, telegram

Установил примеры для Qt, командой: sudo apt-get install qtbase5-examples qtdeclarative5-examples.

После этого перестал запускаться telegram, вот такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Help.

Comment: а как ты ставил телегу?

Comment: я ставил командой sudo apt install telegram-desktop

Comment: установи через `snap` и проблема будет решена

Answer (score 1):

Смотри, что надо сделать. Сначала установи `snapd`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install snapd
```

Далее проверь статус `snap` командой `systemctl status snapd` если `inactive (dead)` то запусти `systemctl start snapd.service`. Теперь ищем `telegram-desktop`:

```
snap find telegram-desktop
```

и устанавливаем:

```
sudo snap install telegram-desktop --classic
```

После этого `telegram` можно запускать как приложение, так и из терминала командой `telegram-desktop`. Если при вводе команды в терминале падает ошибка:

```
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
```

то вводим команду:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.apparmor.service
```

и получаем вывод:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.apparmor.service → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.apparmor.service.
```

Теперь можем юзать `telegram-desktop` через терминал.

Comment: установил командой sudo snap install telegram-desktop, но при запуске требует пароль из смс. Смс не приходит

Comment: при запуске самого телеграма?

Comment: да, телеграма. Приветственное окно как в первый раз

Comment: Ладно, это уже другой вопрос. Запускается криво - командой sudo telegram-desktop, но ошибка с GTK по-прежнему вылазит. Хотелось бы от нее избавиться

Comment: ну у меня приветственное окно было с QR кодом, я не проходил регистрацию по номеру телефона. Просто открыл телегу на телефоне -> Настройки -> Устройства  -> Сканировать QR-код и отсканировал его, вошел автоматически. По поводу ошибки... не пробовал полностью снести старый телеграм `sudo apt remove telegram-desktop`?

Comment: я старый удалил через менеджер приложений